# How to display Returned by json linq list into view?

Tags: javascript, c#, linq, model-view-controller

How to display Returned by json linq list into view?
I tried like below but cant getting list values.

```
$("#Admission_No").live("change", function () {
            var adminssionNo = $(this).val();
            $.getJSON("/../Student_Fee_Allocation/GetStuDetails", { adminssionNo: adminssionNo }, function (list) {

                if (list.length) {
                    alert(list.Registration_Id);
                }          alert(result.Re_Admission_Id);
            });

            //            $.ajax({
            //                type: "GET",
            //                url: "/../Student_Fee_Allocation/GetStuDetails/",
            //                data: { adminssionNo: adminssionNo },
            //                contentType: "application/json;charset=utf-8",
            //                dataType: "json",
            //                success: function (result) {
            //                    debugger;
            //                    alert(result)
            //                },
            //                error: function (response) {
            //                    debugger;
            //                    alert('eror');
            //                }
            //            });

        });
```

in c# getting data in variable and returning as json. but from view side not any response, mean not getting any values and even alert not working.

```
public JsonResult GetStuDetails(string adminssionNo)//long? compId, long? compLocId, 
{
    var list = 
        (from a in db.Student_Re_Admission
         join b in db.Student_Registration on a.Registration_Id equals b.Registration_Id
         where a.Admission_No == adminssionNo && b.Delete_Flag == false
         orderby a.Re_Admission_Id descending
         select new CUSTOM_STUDENT_FEEALLOCATION_DETAIL
         {
             Registration_Id=a.Registration_Id
         }).First();
    return Json(list, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I notice a few issues with your code that I'll elaborate on below :

**Ensuring the Proper Amount of Values Are Returned**

Within your query, you are currently ending it with a `First()` call, which will simply return the first item available from your query. If you are trying to return a collection of items, you should consider using [`ToList()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb342261(v=vs.100).aspx) instead, which should return all of the values in your query :

```
var list = 
    (from a in db.Student_Re_Admission
     join b in db.Student_Registration on a.Registration_Id equals b.Registration_Id
     where a.Admission_No == adminssionNo && b.Delete_Flag == false
     orderby a.Re_Admission_Id descending
     select new CUSTOM_STUDENT_FEEALLOCATION_DETAIL
     {
         Registration_Id=a.Registration_Id
     }).ToList();
```

**The Use of `live()`**

The jQuery `live()` function [was deprecated in jQuery 1.7](http://api.jquery.com/live/) and while this may not be an issue, if you are using a version of jQuery that is less than 1.9, you should consider using it's replacement [`on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) instead.

**Check your Path**

You are currently using a relative path, which might work just fine, but you may want to consider possibly targeting an absolute path instead. If your Javascript code is within a View already (and not in an external file), you could use the [`Url.Action()`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.urlhelper.action(v=vs.118).aspx) method to resolve this :

```
$.getJSON('@Url("GetStuDetails","Student_Fee_Allocation")', ...);
```

or if it's in an external file, you can store it in a `data-*` attribute on the element and reference it :

```
<div id='Admission_No' data-url='@Url("GetStuDetails","Student_Fee_Allocation")'>
   <!-- Your Content Here -->
</div>
```

along with :

```
$.getJSON($(this).data('url'), ...);
```

**Consider using `debugger` to Check Your Output**

If you are still having issues, you may want to consider using the Javascript `debugger` statement to drill deeper into what is being returned from your AJAX call :

```
$.getJSON("/../Student_Fee_Allocation/GetStuDetails", { adminssionNo: adminssionNo }, function (list) {
     // Place a debugger here and run this with your Developer Tools (F12)
     // open to see more information on what list looks like
     debugger;
     if (list.length) {
                alert(list.Registration_Id);
     }          
});
```

Comment: by var its not came ..now its coming by class type variable.

Comment: Can you elaborate on this? I'm afraid I don't understand what you are referring to? Are you saying that no values are being returned from your function or that your parameter isn't being populated in your Controller Action?

Comment: no values are being returned from my function

Comment: but now its ok..working good by class type variable.

Answer (score 0):

The usual when dealing with a single result is to have some div acting as a placeholder and then set the html property of that div to thee result coming from the backend.

Beware that calling .First() in your linq query will throw and error if no data matcha the query parameters, better use FirstOrDefault()